# How do I colour the table based on customer type in tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I want to colour all the rows in my table based on the customer type. If is corporate all the rows are red colour while the individual is blue colour.
How can i do so?

[image]

Comment: Can you please share some sample data for demonstration or otherwise please replicate your problem on `superstore` data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're planning on displaying the data in a table, such as your screenshot, you can explore banding on the format menu. Perhaps the simplest solution, although some compromise is likely.

In general, what you want to do is complicated and not worth the effort. There's a technique in Tableau, the placeholder method, which allows each cell to colour based on certain criteria. Happy to share more about this if you want to know.

Tableau isn't Excel, and those tasks trying to replicate Excel can be frustrating.